# When is too much for cakephp?

Tags: php, mysql, azure, cakephp, zurb-foundation

I've been asked to quickly build a low traffic app with 5 year projections for 700,000 users. I'm banging it out using Azure/CakePHP/MySQL with Zurb for frontend. I'm new to this game and budget is tight until we get funding. This app is to demonstrate and actually be used live initially.

QUESTION: When does CakePHP become clunky/bloated code from a load perspective? Does anyone have stories of largest load CakePHP site?

I'm trying to build in to the business plan of when the rewrite will be required for efficiency. I know there are lots of variables here and I'm probably showing I don't even know enough to know I don't know but I can't find any hints anywhere and I'm 2 weeks into this project. I'm asking here because I land on Stack sites many many times a day to find answers quickly.

Blast away on the newb as long as I learn something from your snark. I don't mind looking stupid as long as it helps me become less stupid even just a little.

Any input unrelated to my exact inquire is highly welcome. It will all mean something. I've been out of the programming world for 12 years. A wee bit has changed in that time. I forgot how much fun it is. I'm back to trying to solve code probs in my sleep.

Comment: This question is off-topic for StackOverflow, as it's opinion-soliciting. There's simply no right answer to this. Plus, you're actually encouraging people to "blast away" at you with snark. Sorry - that's not how this site works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run a site in CakePHP with around 2 million users subscribed and handles a few million hits per day. You should be fine:)

Comment: I once wrote a simple API server that returned a few hundred rows from three or four tables. I let CakePHP/2 write the queries for me and ended up with several thousand almost identical SQL queries per request that took 20 minutes to complete. What I mean is that you can't give definitive answers to such wide questions.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález - then you were doing something drastically wrong.  Something that size should NOT have caused an issue.  Yes, there are certainly ways you can go out of your way to make it run slow, but even just following the online book, and you should be able to handle small things like what you described even without caching, or ANY other type of optimization.

Comment: This isn't an answer. It's you telling someone that you're able to handle your user traffic (based on some unknown set of servers or VMs, undisclosed in your answer). At best, this should be a comment on the question (which is off-topic anyway).

Comment: Of course, the point of my answer was that cakephp has never been a problem. I run the site using 2 webservers, 2 MySQL servers, and 3 elastic search servers.

Comment: @JoséLorenzo Thanks. That is what I wanted to hear someone say. That is way more traffic than we will see for years. I started learning PHP almost 4 weeks ago and saw someone on Stack call CakePHP "bloated". That word has been stuck in my head until now. I know feel comfortable using CakePHP to get through this learning curve. 
Thanks for your time. And thanks everyone else too.